# Differentiating between class level versus character level for alchemist discoveries

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-levels, alchemist

For the discoveries for alchemist, a good chunk of them say "An alchemist must be at least X level before selecting this discovery".

Case in point:

> Explosive Missile: As a standard action, the alchemist can infuse a
>   single arrow, crossbow bolt, or one-handed firearm bullet with the
>   power of his bomb, load the ammunition, and shoot the ranged weapon.
>   He must be proficient with the weapon in order to accomplish this.
>   When the infused ammunition hits its target, it deals damage normally
>   and detonates as if the alchemist had thrown the bomb at the target.
>   If the explosive missile misses, it does not detonate. An alchemist
>   must be at least 4th level before selecting this discovery.

**Does this refer to character level or to class level?** AKA a character who is 3 Barbarian(or any other class really)/2 Alchemist has a character level of 5 but only an Alchemist level of 2 (which some discoveries are based off of Alchemist level explicitly like [Spontaneous Healing](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/alchemist.html#spontaneous-healing))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class abilities refer to Class level unless specified.

See the [MultiClassing Section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement#TOC-Multiclassing) for the exact rules but the part that is important for you specifically is in the last paragraph of the section.

> Note that there are a number of effects and prerequisites that rely on a character's level or Hit Dice. Such effects are always based on the total number of levels or Hit Dice a character possesses, not just those from one class. The exception to this is class abilities, most of which are based on the total number of class levels that a character possesses of that particular class.

Comment: Therein lies the question, since it specifically makes the differentiation for other discoveries, it still begs the question. It is a prereq and not internally consistent with its wording, hense the spontaneous healing example. It is a prereq to determine eligibility, not strength of a power.

Comment: @TechImp I would say this is probably inconsistent wording. Under the ability you linked to is the discovery [Sunlight Bomb](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/alchemist.html#sunlight-bomb) which has similar wording not specifying Alchemist levels but just saying the alchemest needs to be 10th level. The writers are only human :)

Comment: @TechImp Also it seems that the sections that specify Alchemist level are referring to effects such as healing 5 per 2 Alchemist levels or dealing X damage per X Alchemist levels. While the prerequisites section all use the "An Alchemist must be level X before selecting this discovery" format.

Comment: Aye that's why I want to double check. Granted there are other low/no prereq discoveries that I want, but the ability to grab explosive missile right away was tempting enough to double check the ruling on it for a PFS game.